# makefile rebuild even is it up to date

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile always rebuild, don't understand why..

Here it is :

```
SRC =   $(DIR)/my_getnbr.c \
        $(DIR)/my_isneg.c \
        $(DIR)/my_putchar.c \

OBJ =   $(SRC:.c=.o)

DIR =   lib/my

LIB_DIR =   lib

NAME    =   libmy.a

MYH =   include/my.h

BUILD = ar rcs $(NAME) $(DIR)/*.o

MV =    mv $(NAME) $(LIB_DIR)

CP =    cp $(MYH) $(DIR)

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):    $(OBJ)
            $(BUILD)
            $(MV)
            $(CP)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean:clean
    rm -f $(LIB_DIR)/$(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: fclean all re clean
```

I added the `.PHONY` but it changes anything :(

He always do the `BUILD, MV and CP` calls.
If i delete them from the Makefile, it will not rebuild if he is up to date (only with the .OBJ).
Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are moving `libmy.a` to the directory `lib`. the next time you run make it will look for `libmy.a` and since it doesn't exists it will be build.

make will always look for the targets (`libmy.a` in your case) in the current directory. so if you are moving the file to another place make will think the file has not been created.

rule of thumb is: the recipe for a target should always create the file named by the target.

possible solutions:

- not move the file
- qualify the target name with the directory (`NAME = lib/libmy.a`) (perhaps easiest in your case)
- create a dummy file in place of the moved file for make to see the file exists. but this is complicated and prone to missunderstandings if not done well.

Comment: I changed my `NAME = libmy.a` by `NAME    =   $(LIB_DIR)/libmy.a` like you said and it worked perfectly fine ! Thanks a lot ;)